# Command not found for node global packages

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Thanks for looking.
I've installed node and npm and yarn on my mac. But there is a problem with global packages. "Command not found" return every time.
I've tried pretty much everything. Nothing works. Added directories to $PATH.
Interesting thing is that yarn and npm installing global packages in different places.
Yarn: ~/bin
npm: ~/node/bin
I've added them to $PATH also

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin:~/node/bin
```

Here is what echo $PATH returns

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/artur_a/bin:/Users/artur_a/node/bin`

And `npm config get prefix` returns `/Users/myUserName`
Anyway, not working...

Comment: I've noticed after closing and reopening terminal echo $PATH returns usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin . Also even if i call global packages from their directories still command not found returned

Comment: I've been getting the same issue

Comment: You can use `npx` https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b

Answer (score 0):

First, when you use the export command. This command modifies the current working environment (your open terminal).  When you close this window, the exported path modification is lost.

You must make a change to either the system environment settings or the user local environment settings to make this exported path permanent.  If you are using the Mac to login to a linux environment, it is set in ***/etc/profile***.  For linux local settings it will be something like ***/home/myUser/.bash_profile*** depending on your shell.  Add your export commands to the end of the file.

When you open a new terminal, these settings will then be configured in your working environment.

As for not finding global packages, you will find your answers to this problem at https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders  This addresses your prefix questions, path questions and how to find node_modules.